# What type of connector is this and how do you safely disconnect it?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector, high-voltage

While disassembling a Samsung Plasma TV, I've come across this connector labelled "High Voltage" on the power supply PCB.

I'm not sure how to remove it from the PCB. It seems to have two tabs on the side, but I'm not sure how to use them (if at all) to safely remove the connector. I'm erring on the side of caution, and not just yanking out the entire connector by pulling (in case it is like a ribbon connector where you have to disengage something).

Not knowing the name of the connector makes it hard to search for relevant guides online.

[image: image of connector]

[image: image of connector]

[image: image of connector]

---

**== Update ==**

Successfully disconnected following [@transistor's answer below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/614259/73597). Here are pictures of the connectors separated. You can see the hooks. It's hard to catch on camera but the inner wall on the section of the port where the hooks are inserted is slightly elevated giving the hooks something to catch.

[image: image of connector]
[image: image of connector]
[image: image of connector port]

Comment: Pry away the locking tabs and pull hard?

Comment: backlight power connector ... the bar across the rectangular opening should be a latch handle ... lift up on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never seen one of those before but try this ...

[image]

- Squeeze both sides at (1).
- It should flex at the "hinges" (2).
- I imagine there are concealed hooks at (3).
- Then pull upwards. One-hand on the connector while the other holds the board should do the trick.
- If that works then kick self.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! Updated the question with photos if you are curious what the hooks look like.

Comment: @JetBlue, thanks for the update and for accepting this answer.